# Combining two select statement into where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I would like to combine the two select statement below with if else statement into one select statement with the conditional expression in where clause. How could it be achieve?

```
@DefaultMemberID = 2

IF @DefaultMemberID IS NOT NULL THEN 
   SELECT * FROM MemberProfile
   WHERE MemberID = @DefaultMemberID OR MemberID = NULL
ELSE
   SELECT * FROM MemberProfile
```

How to combine this into one select statement as follow:

```
SELECT * FROM MemberProfile
WHERE
  WHEN @DefaultMemberID IS NOT NULL THEN
  MemberID = @DefaultMemberID OR MemberID IS NULL
  ELSE do not take memberID into account when querying
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you are going to have trouble believing this but that is just

```
WHERE @DefaultMemberID is null 
   or MemberID = @DefaultMemberID 
   OR MemberID is NULL
```

Comment: How is this different from MM's answer posted an hour previous?

Comment: @MartinSmith It is not different.  I did not notice it and I guess neither did the OP.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way to combine your queries.

```
SELECT * FROM MemberProfile
   WHERE MemberID = @DefaultMemberID OR MemberID IS NULL OR @DefaultMemberID IS NULL
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

**Note :** You cannot compare `NULL` with `=` operator. You need to use `IS` to check the existence of `NULL`

Comment: @Hogan - yeah missed that condition :)